# trouble with lists and biblio and quotes indenting

Tags: lists

lists and quotes and references are all indented about half way into the page and print off page ... the is perhaps related to \item not working for the lists and biblio though this wouldn't affect the quotes ...
I am using mac os 10.10.2 and texshop 3.51

Comment: We have no chance to understand what is wrong if you don't give us more information. Please try to build a minimal example. cf http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that. More often than not you'll actually find the solution to your problem while trying to do so.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE!